# Redirecting a user when payment is completed in an django e commerce website

Tags: django

I want to Redirect  a user when payment is completed in an django  e commerce site .IAM using a payment gateway that sends a json object on the submitted webhook that contains payment status.

Comment: After the user pays it goes to a payment processing page so I want to Redirect the user from that page

Comment: Sounds like the easiest would be to use frontend JavaScript to have the payment processing page periodically refresh itself, and the view code to figure out whether the webhook has been called and payment succeeded for the particular transaction.

Comment: Which type of payment gateway are you using and is it a unique product or multiple products? If you are using stripe for a simple charge it is pretty simple setup if it's for multiple products its pretty hard. please provide your question with more details.

Comment: Am using beyonic gateway below is the link to it's documentation https://github.com/beyonic/beyonic-python